# TableView and List Data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to display a `List` of icons (which are referred simply by their path) in a `TableView` that has x-amount of columns and any number of cells that are required to display all the icons.

The plan was to display the icons in such a way that the `TableView` acts as a "multi-lined" `ListView`.. so that they go from left to the right.

It's the first time I'm using the `TableView` control, and I'm a bit confused of how to achieve this.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Are all icons displayed in just one row(multiple columns)? or there is one icon per row?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well.. to be honest I'm not sure of the implementation myself, I'm a novice when it comes to the TableView! It's just that I have over 2000 icons, and a ListView wasn't practical enough to display them.. so now I am attempting to display them in a TableView that has a visible width of "8 icons" and height of "5 icons". This is fixed, and all icons are the same size. I don't need any dynamic resizing. But I can't quite figure out how to lay them out in to the table structure. Using simply setItems() just sets the the icons for ALL 8 columns (duplicated).

Comment: Why do you have 8 columns in a TableView ? Have you consider using [Pagination](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/pagination.htm) in ListView ?

Comment: Well it was just a quick test to get something up and running.. No I haven't even heard of the Pagination before, but it surely looks interesting! I shall try it.

Comment: Well, that didn't take too long! Pagination and GridPane made it trivial! Thank you.

Comment: The only "problem" I have is that for some reason the Pagination Controls are much smaller than in the examples on the page you linked. Even though there would definitely should be enough space to show them in bigger size. Any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that depicts your problem ? The most probable reason would be some configuration in the size of the layout containing the Pagination Control

Comment: I just tried to reproduce it in a simple test case.. and couldn't. The thing is I am showing the Pagination Control in a ControlsFX Dialog, perhaps that is the issue. I believe I can manage to figure it out on my own. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So, as ItachiUchiha suggested, I ended up using a Pagination control with a GridPane, and it works very nicely.

Here's the code if anyone stumbles upon the same thing..

```
    List<String> allEntries = Icons.getAllEntries();
    int numCols = 8;
    int numRows = 5;
    int numPages = allEntries.size() / (numCols * numRows);
    Pagination pagination = new Pagination(numPages);
    Collections.sort(allEntries);
    pagination.setPageFactory(pageIndex -> {
        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        for (int y = 0; y < numRows; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < numCols; x++) {
                int index = numCols * y + x + (pageIndex * numCols * numRows);
                String path = allEntries.get(index);
                Image image = new Image(path, true);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                imageView.setFitWidth(64);
                imageView.setFitHeight(64);
                layout.add(imageView, x, y);
                imageView.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                    // Do stuff
                });
            }
        }
        return layout;
    });
```